# jQuery undefined function in wordpress plugin which creates a fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar, undefined-function

I am creating a plugin which uses the jQuery fullCalender.

The code appears to all be working fine however when the page fully loads and my shortcode populates its appropriate html and javascript I get the following error:

[image]

So from this I can gather that jQuery resolves ok - but somehow the calendar does not? Can somebody please help me! It may be because I am using OptimizePress which might be including its own copy of jQuery - and my plugin is also including a copy of jQuery and the calendar. But I dont know how to make sure i reference my own jQuery or make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: check page source and see if the url to the calender is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script to add the script to my generated document